# commons-math differentiation result is 0

Tags: java, apache-commons-math, differentiation

I'm trying to use commons-math library for some numerical differentiation task. I've built a very simple function using DerivativeStructures which I thought would work; apparently I was wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DerivativeStructure x0 = new DerivativeStructure(2, 2, 2.0);
    DerivativeStructure y0 = new DerivativeStructure(2, 2, 4.0);
    DerivativeStructure xi = x0.pow(2);
    DerivativeStructure yi = y0.pow(2);
    DerivativeStructure f = xi.add(yi);

    System.out.println(f.getValue());
    System.out.println(f.getPartialDerivative(1, 0)); // (?)
    System.out.println(f.getPartialDerivative(0, 1)); // (?)
}
```

I'm trying to get the 1st and 2nd order partial derivatives of a the multivariate function f(x)=x^2+y^2 at point (2.0, 4.0). As a result I'd expect 4.0 for df/dx and 8.0 for df/dy as first order partials. 2.0 for second order partials. I however am getting the correct f(x,y) value and I don't even have the slightest idea from this javadoc. I saw a couple questions here on stackoverflow with some comments about the opaque documentation for commons-math but not a working example on multivariate functions. Univariate I can work out, but not this...

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you haven't really specified 2 independent variables x0, y0 but only 1. With `DerivativeStructure` x0, y0 are actually seen as functions themselves depending on an implicit vector of variables `p`. For each independent variable you have to give a different index into the `p` vector of independent variables. What you need to do is:

```
DerivativeStructure x0 = new DerivativeStructure(2, 2, 0, 2.0);
DerivativeStructure y0 = new DerivativeStructure(2, 2, 1, 4.0);
```

Where the third parameter(s) 0 and 1 indicate 2 different indexes in the `p` vector therefore two different independent variables. If you omit this parameter when creating a `DerivativeStructure`, 0 is assumed so in your code x0, y0 are not independent.

[Further Reading](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.7_Differentiation)